# How to create C static libraries in Cargo?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I want  my Rust project to be compiled as a C library in both static and dynamic libraries.

I added this to my Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
crate-type=["cdylib"]
```

but it only creates `.so` libraries. How do I create `.a` ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `staticlib` for a `.a` as listed on https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html

Comment: Thanks. This is confusing, `cdylib` looks like `c dynamic library` while `staticlib` looks like a Rust static library.

Comment: I thought the c static library should be named as cstaticlib too. :)